# Tips for USACO competition-type problems/how to speed this up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

To start, sorry for the vague title. I'm not even sure if this type of question counts as best practices on this site. If it doesn't, I'm sorry, and please try not to destroy all my reputation points. Anyway, here's my question: I'm new to USACO-type coding competitions, and decided to try some USACO problems. I will link the problem I did here, since it would make this post long if I included the whole thing([Bessie's CS Degree Problem](https://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=1131#)). To solve it, I wrote this code(this ignores the i/o for the purposes of the question)

```py
class Paper:
    def __init__(self,citationNum):
        self.citations=citationNum
        self.hasBeenCited=False
    def citeInSurvey(self):
        self.citations+=1
        self.hasBeenCited=True

for h in range(paperNum1,-1,-1):
        paperNum=paperNum1
        citationResume=citationResume1
        citationsInSurvey=citationsInSurvey1
        for i in range(citationsInSurvey):
            for paper in citationResume:
                if not paper.hasBeenCited and paper.citations==h-1:
                    paper.citeInSurvey()
        papersAtLeastH=0
        for paper in citationResume:
            if paper.citations>=h:
                papersAtLeastH+=1
        if papersAtLeastH>=h:
            print(h)
            break
```

I wrote this in a hurry, so some of the variable names might not make sense. When `citationResume` is several thousand papers long, it times out and counts as a wrong answer by USACO standards. however, there can be as many as 100k papers at play in the test cases. How do I speed up this code that much? This isn't the type of question I would normally ask, but I think that an answer might give me a good introduction into the competition side of coding, where being fast and easy to write has higher priority over making the most immediate sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that if I sort citationResume beforehand, it doesn't take as long as I expected and lets me do things faster.